# How to populate Django Quill Field from ORM

Tags: django, django-orm, quill

I am trying to save an object with a Quill Field in django via the ORM. I am using the [django-quill-editor](https://pypi.org/project/django-quill-editor/) module from PyPI

Here is the model:

```
from django_quill.fields import QuillField

class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False, null=False)
    description = QuillField(blank=False, null=False)
```

Here is the code for creating a `Product` instance:

```
product = Product.objects.create(
    name='Sample Product',
    description='{"delta":"{\"ops\":[{\"insert\":\"test desription\\n\\n\"}]}","html":"<p>test desription</p><p><br></p>"}',
)
product.save()
```

This fails with the following error:

```
django_quill.quill.QuillParseError: Failed to parse value({"delta":"{"ops":[{"insert":"test desription\n\n"}]}","html":"<p>test desription</p><p><br></p>"})
```

I have tried supplying a plain text value and I get the same result. I got the json from another row that is already in the database.

Any idea how to do this via the ORM?

Comment: This might be useful, please have a look: https://github.com/LeeHanYeong/django-quill-editor/issues/13#issuecomment-776863989